# ESD protection for DC supply line

Tags: esd, tvs, passive-filter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLAaRj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm working on a system that will go into ESD testing, The system is powered by an external regulated DC voltage.

I'm now using an LC filter for High frequency noise reduction, but i'm not sure if this alone will help with ESD.

I have added the supply voltage schematic, the VCC_5V_PIN comes directly from the connector, VCC_5V is connected directly to the ICs in the circuit with decoupling caps connected to each IC.

Other electrical signals comment from the connector are ground and 4 Pins for SPI communication(MOSI,MISO,SCLK and CS) which are protected by TVS diodes.

Should i use a TVS diode to help for ESD protection or just change to a PI filter by adding a capacitor close to the connector ?

Comment: You should include a **schematic**, just adding TVS diodes everywhere is usually "safe" (should not harm) but if they're not needed, why add them? It depends on how the ESD sensitve devices (ICs, transistors) are connected to the connector wether additional protection is needed. And for that we need a schematic.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie can't post a schematic as this is confidential for the company i work for, but on the supply line i have a reverse voltage protection Mosfet transistor right after the LC and a 10uf capacitor, all the ICs have decoupling capacitors connected to their supply voltage, also the circuit should survive a 2KV,4KV and 8KV ESD voltage.

Comment: You could still make a drawing of the relevant parts using the schematic editor, if you edit your question there's a small button for drawing a schematic. Imagining a circuit from some text: it is not going to happen I'm afraid.

Comment: If the supply connector is the **only** electrical input, you probably do not need extra ESD protection. A series inductor (which you have) and decoupling caps should provide enough protection. Also any ICs connected to the supply will clamp (limit) the voltage resulting from ESD.

Comment: You added a schematic, good. Now it is clear that the PMOS is in series with the supply.  Note that you have drawn the source at the right, there is also a drain-source diode present in the IRF9530, do make sure it will be in reverse mode when the PMOS is off. That would mean that the source has to be at the **left** side! But ignoring that: the ESD can reach the PMOS gate-source. I would just add a TVS diode in parallel with C1, that should protect the PMOS.